# Facebook Oauth Login Popup Stuck After Credentials Entered

Tags: javascript, facebook, gwt, facebook-oauth

I have integrated facebook OAuth login to my GWT app.  The facebook API takes the credentials in its authentication popup, but the process gets stuck at the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&domain=www.myapp.com
&api_key=mykey&app_id=myid&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&client_id=myid
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect
%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df237c9c7bc%26origin
%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.myapp.com%252Ff32ad475a%26domain
%3Dwww.myapp.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame
%3Df2ae130a84&origin=1&response_type=token%2Csigned_request
```

Facebook login was working for my app before, but this problem started to occur recently.

Anyone out there experiencing the same problem, know of a fix/workaround?  Is this an issue with the Facebook API?

Thanks!

Comment: This problem solved itself after about a week.  It must have been a problem on the Facebook side.

Comment: pls close this question

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved itself after about a week. It must have been a problem on the Facebook side.